# Разбиение строки на заданные размерностью подстроки

Tags: java

Задача:
есть строка, надо разбить на подстроки указанной величины.
Указанная величина <=30 символов в строке.

Я пошел таким путем

Создал строку, допустим:

```
String testString = "The Supreme Court heard arguments in a major case, debating diversity in higher education and the courts’ role in policing how much weight admissions officers may assign to race.";
```

разбил ее на массив слов

```
String arrStr[] = testString.split(" ");
```

Далее пошел таким вот способом, но вижу что он не правильный, так как он постоянно складывает значение [i] и [i + 1], то есть два следующих слова не доходя до ~30 символов в строке

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arrStr[i].length() <= 30) {
            arrStr[i] += " " + arrStr[i + 1];
            System.out.println(arrStr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: всем спасибо за ответы, да последний автор точно описал задачу спасибо, отныне буду внимательнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смею предположить, что автор не до конца указал условие задачи - не просто разбить на подстроки по 30 символов, а чтобы эти подстроки(фразы) содержали целые слова и не выходили за предел 30 символов.

На всякий случай оставлю реализацию:

```
String arrWords[] = testString.split(" ");  // Массив слов
ArrayList<String> arrPhrases = new ArrayList<String>(); // Коллекция подстрок(фраз)

StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder(); // Буфер для накопления фразы
int cnt = 0;   // Счётчик, чтобы не выйти за пределы 30 символов
int index = 0; // Индекс элемента в массиве arrWords. Сразу указывает на первый элемент
int length = arrWords.length; // Общее количество слов (длина массива)

while (index != length) {  // Пока не дойдём до последнего элемента
  if (cnt + arrWords[index].length() <= 30) { // Если текущая фраза + текущее слово в массиве arrWords не превышает 30
    cnt += arrWords[index].length() + 1;  // То увеличиваем счётчик
    stringBuffer.append(arrWords[index]).append(" ");  // и накапливаем фразу
    index++;   // Переходим на следующее слово
  } else {   // Фраза превысит лимит в 30 символов
    arrPhrases.add(stringBuffer.toString());   // Добавляем фразу в коллекцию
    stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    cnt = 0;                                   // Обнуляем счётчик
  }

}

if (stringBuffer.length() > 0) {
   arrPhrases.add(stringBuffer.toString());       // Забираем "остатки"
}

for (String elem : arrPhrases) {
   System.out.println(elem);    // Вывод на экран
}
```

Результат для фразы, приведённой в вопросе:

```
The Supreme Court heard 
arguments in a major case, 
debating diversity in higher 
education and the courts’ role 
in policing how much weight 
admissions officers may assign 
to race.
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем так сложно?

В Джава работа со строками сплошное удовольствие.

Для вашей задачи подойдёт метод **testString.substring()** которая разбивает строку по индексу (метод перегруженный - testString.substring(5) - разобьёт строку от 0 до 4 символов, textString.substring(5,10) - с 4 - 9 если не ошибаюсь).

Для поиска слова/знака в строке есть метод **testString.indexOf("Text");**

Пример:

```
int one = testString.IndexOf("Hello");
String text = testString.substring(one,testString.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String newStr  = str.replaceAll("(.{30})", "$1|");
String[] newStrings = newStr.split("\\|");
```

По регулярному выражению ищем окончания 30 символа и заменяем последовательность на саму себя + символ "|". Далее разбиваем строку по этому символу.

Comment: Идея с 30-м символом правильная, а вот регулярные выражения, замена и разбиение (split) совершенно ни к чему (абсолютно неэффективно).

--

Надо  просто (по charAt()) двигаться назад и проверять символ на принадлежность к разделителям слов. Потом substring()-ом выделять подстроку от "текущего начала" до этого разделителя и добавлять ее к результату (печатать). Сместить "текущее начало" и зациклить.

Вот и все.